# How can I get output of class in custom formatted way python? (NGROK tunnel names)

Tags: python, pyngrok

I am using ngrok to ofcourse portforward my local system but when getting tunnels names `ngrok.get_tunnels()` it outputs in weird way so when I check the type of its output it shows that it is a **class**. Output like this

`[<NgrokTunnel: "http://4527-124-123-122-140.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:3243">, <NgrokTunnel: "https://4527-124-123-122-140.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:3243">]`

How can I take the URL names from it like I want in this way

`HTTP tunnel: http://4527-124-123-122-140.ngrok.io`
`HTTPS tunnel: https://4527-124-123-122-140.ngrok.io`

**Below is my code which is just 3 lines to give the output**

```
from pyngrok install ngrok

ngrok.connect(5000, "http")
ngrok.get_tunnels()
```

Comment: That's a list of *instances* of the class. You are getting the string representation of the list, which includes the string representation of the instances. Check the documentation, as it should explain how to get the URL  from the instance.

Comment: Read it whole.. no luck!!

Comment: What is the code that *generates* this output? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @chepner I have edited my question showing the code

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the return value of `get_tunnels`, so that you can iterate over it.

```
from pyngrok install ngrok

ngrok.connect(5000, "http")
tunnels = ngrok.get_tunnels()

for t in tunnels:
    print(t.public_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a loop through each of the ngrok objects and then do ngrok[i].public_url to get the url attribute of the class

Comment: No actually these are not objects even though I tried what you say, i get this `TypeError: 'NgrokTunnel' object is not iterable`

because its type is `<class 'pyngrok.ngrok.NgrokTunnel'>`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: have you tried doing just ngrok.public_url ?

Comment: `url = ngrok.connect(5000,"http")` `url.public_url` but this just gives the http link not https.... I guess I'll need regex to take the url out